# Is this the best/correct way to use the DevExpress ASPxGridView to edit a List<T>?

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, editing, aspxgridview, ilist

Would someone who knows DeveExpess ASPxGridView take a look at this.

Is this the best/correct way to use the grid to edit a List?

I have an object of Type ItemModel and the code below is used to allow an ASP.NET Web Site user to do CRUD operations on list of ItemModels.

My problem is that it seems too complex and I suspect I am not taking good advantage of the Grid.

For simplicity, I have left the Database Access Code that will load and save the list of ItemModels.

```
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        BindGrid();            
    }

    protected void OnRowInserting(object sender, ASPxDataInsertingEventArgs e)
    {
        IList<ItemModel> itemModels = CachedModels;
        int lineID = 0;
        if (itemModels .Count > 0)
        {
            lineID = itemModels[itemModels.Count - 1].LineID + 1;
        }

        ItemModel itemModel = new ItemModel()
        {
             , Code = e.NewValues["Code"] == null ? string.Empty : e.NewValues["Code"].ToString()
             , Name = e.NewValues["Name"] == null ? string.Empty : e.NewValues["Name"].ToString()
             , DateCreated = DateTime.Now
             , DateUpdated = DateTime.Now
        };
        itemModels.Add(itemModel);

        CachedModels = itemModels;

        ASPxGridView aspxGridView = (ASPxGridView)sender;
        aspxGridView.CancelEdit();
        e.Cancel = true;

        BindGrid();
    }
    protected void OnRowUpdating(object sender, ASPxDataUpdatingEventArgs e)
    {
        IList<ItemModel> itemModels = CachedModels;
        int lineID = Convert.ToInt32(e.Keys[0].ToString());

        ItemModel itemModel = null;
        foreach (ItemModel model in itemModels)
        {
            if (model.LineID == lineID)
            {
                itemModel = model;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (itemModel != null)
        {

            itemModel.Code = e.NewValues["Code"] == null ? string.Empty : e.NewValues["Code"].ToString();
            itemModel.Name = e.NewValues["Name"] == null ? string.Empty : e.NewValues["Name"].ToString();
            containerItemModel.DateUpdated = DateTime.Now;

            itemModels[lineID] = itemModel;
            CachedModels = itemModels;
        }
        ASPxGridView aspxGridView = (ASPxGridView)sender;
        aspxGridView.CancelEdit();
        e.Cancel = true;

        BindGrid();
    }
    protected void OnRowDeleting(object sender, ASPxDataDeletingEventArgs e)
    {
        IList<ItemModel> itemModels = CachedModels;

        int lineID = Convert.ToInt32(e.Keys[0].ToString());

        ItemModel itemModel = null;
        foreach (ItemModel model in itemModels)
        {
            if (model.LineID == lineID)
            {
                itemModel = model;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (itemModel != null)
        {
            itemModels.Remove(itemModel);
            CachedModels = itemModels;
        }

        ASPxGridView aspxGridView = (ASPxGridView)sender;
        aspxGridView.CancelEdit();
        e.Cancel = true;

        BindGrid();
    }

    private void BindGrid()
    {
        grdItems.DataSource = CachedModels;
        grdItems.DataBind();
    }
    private IList<ItemModel> CachedModels
    {
        get
        {
            List<ItemModel> models= (List<ItemModel>)Session["ItemModels"];
            if (models == null)
            {
                models= new List<ItemModel>();
                Session["ItemModels"] = models;
            }
            return models;
        }
        set
        {
            Session["ItemModels"] = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you contact DX directly?

Comment: Getting a decent response from them takes so much effort. Have you seen their help/code samples?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your current code is quite correct.

Here is the suggested way from DX:

[ASPxGridView - How to implement CRUD operations with a custom data source](http://www.devexpress.com/issue=KA18686)